# rewriting a superglobal php variable (simple shorthand functions)

Tags: php

Can anyone specify why you might want to rewrite a superglobal variable in php.

For instance, i came across this the other day:

```
function post($x, $y = ''){
    return array_key_exists($x, $_POST) ? $_POST[$x] : $y;
}
```

It's just shorthand for $_POST i believe...

other than being able to use post and typing two less characters, what would be the other benefits for rewriting?

Any and all feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's entirely a personal preference. Code reduction and eschewing repetitive workarounds is always a good thing. If you need it often enough, why not. You'll soon want a few more features though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function accepts a second parameter which it returns as a *default value* if the requested parameter does not exist. So it's shorthand for:

```
isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : 'bar';
```

Is it worth it? Meh...

Answer (score 1):

It's specifying a default value to use if the `$_POST` variable isn't present.  The function defaults to an empty string, but when calling it you could specify a different value if you wanted to:

```
echo post('foo', 'bar');
```

The above would output 'foo' if `$_POST['foo']` is present, otherwise it would output "bar"

Comment: Thank you as well, it's perfectly clear now.